# how can i find the temporary folder that Jetty host the web app?

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I deployed gwt app to Jetty using maven-jetty-plugin, with 'mvn jetty:run' i have access my app, but it kept telling one file is not found, i need to know where Jetty host those apps so i can dig into the web app folder to see if that file is really missing. how can i find it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using windows

```
USER_DIRECTORY\Local Settings\Temp\jetty_........ folders
```

Comment: i use Mac, and i tried the following folder: /var/folders/nz/nZcX9O1iEMSKRZHCbqdF8E+++TI(please don't ask me how i get to there...), then i saw three folders: -Caches-, -Tmp-, TemporaryItems, i believed the apps were stored in the folder -Tmp-, but i cannot get into it useing 'cd', any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By default it should be in your target directory.